# Процесс компиляции исходного кода в нативный

Tags: c++, компиляция

Не могли бы вы описать точный процесс компиляции исходного кода в нативный, спасибо.

Comment: Эээ. на эту тему можно несколько диссертаций написать.

Comment: Вобще до некоторых пор мне было понятно, но позже когда я узнал про make все перемешалось.

Comment: Чем же смутила эта утилита? К генерации кода она имеет отношение весьма слабое, её функция -- отслеживать зависимости, и выполнять предписанные действия, если эти зависимости нарушаются (цель имеет время создания/изменения раньше, чем файл, от которого она зависит).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно взять исходный код какого-нибудь компилятора и посмотреть) Или взять какую-нибудь книжку почитать, например "Компиляторы: принципы, технологии, инструменты" Альфреда Ахо и др.

Для ассемблера, в простейшем случае, команды заменяются на соответствующие им коды операций.

Comment: @insolor только таких ассемблеров в настоящее время вряд не найти. Да и раньше тоже. Символическая адресация куда важней мнемонических кодов.

Answer (score 1):

Поддерживаю Драконью книгу.

Если попроще и попримитивнее - можно почитать «Create Your Own Freaking Awesome Programming Language» (купить на createyourproglang.com, где скачать бесплатно без sms — знают в поисковике), там «на пальцах» просто и понятно создание интерпретатора и компилятора. Не в x86/x86_64, а llvm и самодельную виртуальную машину, но особой разницы никакой. Правда, книга совсем простая — скажем, вопросы оптимизации там не затрагиваются вообще.

Comment: «Create Your Own Freaking Awesome Programming Language» - есть Русский вариант этой книги?

Comment: Не встречал и сомневаюсь, что переводилось.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала компилятор разделяет исходный файл на токены (слова и знаки), строит абстрактное синтаксическое дерево (AST), анализируя их. Полученное дерево уже можно выполнять, интерпретируя. По этому дереву можно генерировать код. Это делается разными способами: генерация вручную под конткретную платформу, либо создание байткода для .NET, Java или LLVM. Байткод LLVM можно компилировать в машинный код под любую поддерживаемую платформу.

Сам захотел написать компилятор. Нашёл уже статью. [Вот](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/programming/119850/) учебник, в котором пошагово описано создание своего компилятора с использованием LLVM.