# Генерировать машинный код на C++

Tags: c++, компилятор, машинный-код

Я пишу свой компилятор для простого игрового движка. В интернете нашел информацию только о том, как сгенерировать байт код, но мне нужно, чтобы игра написания на этом движке компилировалась в машиный код и потом ее можно было запускать на операционной системе Windows.

Как с помощью С++ написать программу, которая создаст другую программу под Windows? То есть я имею ввиду просто в двух словах объяснить, как пишут компиляторы, которые генерируют машиный код.

Comment: не думаю, что кто то будет  против вашего желания, но вопрос то в чем...

Comment: Вопрос в том, как вообще можно сгенерировать машиный код, то есть есть приложение A и при запуске этого приложения, приложение A должно создать приложение B, как это делается?

Comment: *просто в двух словах* - месье оптимист... Почитайте [Компиляторы: принципы, технологии и инструменты](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Компиляторы:_принципы,_технологии_и_инструменты) для осознания масштаба

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Процесс компиляции исходного кода в нативный](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/77995/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9)

Comment: А зачем вообще нужен особенный компилятор для игрового движка? Почему нельзя компилировать его стандартным компилятором?

Comment: Статейка небольшая, но, возможно, это тоже окажется полезным и интересным для Вас в данном деле. [Ссылка](https://tproger.ru/translations/how-to-create-programming-language/)

Comment: Возможно самым простым решением будет "двойная трансляция". 1) переводите текст со своего языка в исходный текст Си (или другого компилируемого языка) 2) вызываете транслятор с этого языка.